# How to play songs from list (array) and not from Media picker

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, media-player, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have an app where I have the user pick songs, and then those songs get stored into a Core Data table.  I store  the Song Name, Artist, Album, and song duration.  I need to replay this back.  I thought I could load the song names into an array of some sort and play them that way.  Should I be storing the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID as well and any other attributes I should be saving?

Also, how do I then play the songs back from said array.  Any samples? tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

-PaulS.

Answer (score 0):

use the MPMusicPlayerController class
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

and the AddMusic sample code from Apple
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845

and yes, the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID is how you will reference the tracks - it remains consistent across syncs.